# Finite switching of balls between covering of a compact set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a compact set, and let $\mathfrak{C} = \{B_1, B_2, \cdots, B_m \}$ a finite covering of $S$ with $m$ open balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $R = \min(r(B_1), \cdots, r(B_m))$ (where $r(B_i)$ denotes the radious of the open ball $B_i$).

Does there exist an absolute constant $c_n$ depending on $n$ and **not depending on $m$** such that for any two points $Q_1, Q_2 \subset S$ with $d(Q_1, Q_2) \leq r$, there exists points $P_1, P_2, \cdots, P_{c_n}$ and balls $B_{i_1}, B_{i_2}, \cdots, B_{i_n}$  such that $P_j, P_{j+1} \in B_{i_{j+1}}$ for all $j < n$ and $P_1, Q_1 \in B_{i_1}$ and $P_n, Q_2 \in B_{i_n}$.

PS: If this is true, then that would provide another proof for the following fact: If $f: K \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ with $K$ compact and $f$ continuous, then $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: This https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_number_lemma might be interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $S = \{0, 1\}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and the open cover $(-1, 1), (0, 2)$ of $S$. Now for $Q_0 = 0, Q_1 = 1$ in $S$ we have $d(Q_1, Q_2) \leq 1$ and no such sequence of $P_i$'s exist, because in order to be in one of the open balls, one must be either $0$ or $1$ and if two points are in the same ball, they are the same.

Comment: You didn't say that it was connected, only compact. Do you want to edit your question?

Comment: Any finite set is compact.

Comment: Sorry I mean my question is still true since the balls need not be distinct (I thought I need not mention that since you can always take $m=1$)

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. How does my example not apply to your question; which of the conditions does it not satisfy?

Comment: Oh yes, you are indeed right and the answer to my question is negative ! What would be the answer when $S$ is connected btw ?

Comment: Try to post a new question (and give a link to this question saying "the disconnect case is false: LINK") and we can talk there. ... I'll think about it, because I am not sure.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}$ it might be true, but in $\mathbb{R}^d$ it is false. As follows:

Comment: Fix any two points $x$ and $y$. You can take $R$ to be as large as you like and only use balls of radius $R$. Just take the balls, like a linked chain, and walk away from $x$ in a direction opposite that of $y$. Then once you have gotten more than, say, $3R$ away from the both of them, start to make a semi-circle path around to the other side where $y$ is, then go toward $y$. If you want, you can make $S$ to be a path from $x$ to $y$ that lies entirely inside each of these balls.

Comment: Oh yeah you're right ! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: If $S$ is a connected (non-empty) subset of $\mathbb{R}$, it is then an interval so if $x, y \in S$, $[x,y] \subset S$. For any point $t$ between $x$ and $y$, there is some interval of radius at least $|x-y|$ containing $t$, and hence it contains $x$ or $y$ as well. If one such interval contains both $x$ and $y$ then we are done with only needing one interval. If one $t \in [x,y]$ has an interval containing $x$ and one containing $y$, then we are done with needing two intervals. Else, we get a function $f: [x,y] \to \{x,y\}$ where we map $t$ to the point in one of its intervals. ...Continued..

Comment: Note: because $f(x) = x$ and $f(y) = y$, by the intermediate value theorem, $f$ cannot be continuous. Let $t_0 = \sup \{t \in [x,y]: f(t) = x\}$. If $x < t_0 < y$, then for any $t_0 < t < y, f(t) = y$ and there is a sequence  $t_n \to t$ such that $f(t_n) = x$..However, since the interval containing $t_0$ is open, it will contain one such $t_n$ and one such $t > t_0$ and so the intervals of $t_0, t_n,$ and $t$ give you three steps. This gives three intervals needed. (You can check that this is actually attained and is not an over-estimate that cannot happen). .... Continued....

Comment: Wow, I'm giving a bounty of +50 to your answer for the comments !

Comment: If $t_0 = x$, then for any $t$ such that $x < t < y$, $f(t) = y$ and since any interval containing $x$ is open, it will contain some $t$ such that $y >  t > x$ and so you only need two steps in this case. Likewise, if $t_0 = y$, then there is a sequence of $t_n \to t_0 = y$ such that $f(t_n) = x$. Then since any open interval containing $y$ will contain some $t_n$, we see that we only need two intervals in this case as well. So for $\mathbb{R}$, the number is at most $2$.

Comment: Oops... the actual bound is $2$, I will edit the previous comments to explain why.

Comment: Apparently, I can't edit it. ... So, in the case that $x < t_0 < y$ we have $t_n \to t$ and $t_0 < t < y$ where $t_n$ and $t$ are in the interval of $t_0$. However, we know that $f(t_0) =x$ or $f(t_0) = y$. In the former case, we may take the intervals for $t_0$ and $t$. In the latter case, we can take the intervals for $t_n$ and $t_0$.

Note: In the case that $f(t_0) = x$, it might be the case that $t_n = t_0$ for all large $n$ which might happen particularly if there are no points that map to $x$ near $t_0$. This doesn't cause any problems, since the proof uses only  $t_n \to t_0$.

Comment: The answer $2$ also makes sense.